# Prevent Code From Deleting Table in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have some linked tables in my access DB, these tables are used in a make table query where the employee data is grabbed from. There is a connection check that runs at the very beginning, but when there is no connection the table gets deleted. Is there a line of code I can add anywhere that can tell the DB not to delete the table if there is no connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DAO Object Library offers a TableDefs Object that has the attribute you are looking for (called "Connect"). Using this you can scan your database to determine if a table is a local, linked or ODBC connection.

Below is a piece of code I wrote a LONG time ago to "document" databases attributes in an Excel Spreadsheet using the DAO model. I've included the piece that specifically refers to table attributes (so understand that I've excluded the database lookup and creating the Excel spreadsheet). Hopefully this will give you an idea of how you can use this attribute to create the logic you are looking for.

```
Dim oDb As DAO.Database
Dim oTbl As DAO.TableDef
Dim oTbls As DAO.TableDefs

'... A lot of code to open the appropriate database, create an excel spreadsheet
'and begin pasting DAO attributes into a template...

Dim oWkbk As Excel.Workbook
With oWkbk.Sheets("Tables")
    .Select
    .Range("B1").Value = TrimToChar(DbName, "\", True, True)
    .Range("B1").Font.Bold = True
    .Range("B1").Font.Size = 14
    .Range("B3").Value = "Name"
    .Range("C3").Value = "Linked"
    .Range("D3").Value = "Linked DB"
    .Range("E3").Value = "Date Created"
    .Range("F3").Value = "Last Updated"
    .Range("G3").Value = "Record Count"
    .rows("3:3").Font.Bold = True
    .rows("3:3").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With




Set oTbls = oDb.TableDefs

For Each oTbl In oTbls          
        With oWkbk.Sheets("Tables")
            .Range("B" & i).Value = oTbl.Name
            .Range("E" & i).Value = oTbl.DateCreated
            .Range("F" & i).Value = oTbl.LastUpdated
        End With            
****'HERES THE PART TO PAY ATTENTION TO:****
        If oTbl.Connect = "" Then
            With oWkbk.Sheets("Tables")
                .Range("C" & i).Value = "No"
                .Range("G" & i).Value = oTbl.RecordCount
            End With
        ElseIf Left(oTbl.Connect, 4) = "ODBC" Then
            With oWkbk.Sheets("Tables")
                .Range("C" & i).Value = "ODBC"
            End With
********************************************

        Else
            With oWkbk.Sheets("Tables")
                .Range("C" & i).Value = "Yes"
                .Range("D" & i).Value = TrimToChar(oTbl.Connect, "\", True, True)
            End With
        End If
Next oTbl
```

Comment: I am confused, how can I implement this into my code to be sure the table is not deleted in case there is no established connection?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question... I thought you wanted to know which tables are local vs. which tables are have a linked connection. Is that not what you are asking?

Comment: I am trying to prevent the table from being delete if there is no connection established. SO basically if there is no connection with the SQL server the code stops running so the make table query isn't executed.

Comment: Okay, so I think there is some confusion when you say "connection". In MS Access there are two primary types of connections 1) Linked Table connection from another MS Access Database and 2) ODBC (or some other driver) connection. The difference between these can be seen in the icon: #1 is a normal table with an arrow while #2 is a world icon. If your code is set up to delete a table from the database if it cannot establish the #2 type of connection then you should already have what you need available in your source code... you'll just have to find it. Other options available are to explore ...

Comment: ...that TableDefs object as it should contain some reference to an attribute you can use to tap into the Linked Table Manager (which is ultimately what you are trying to do). I do have to say though, I'm questioning why your code is doing an auto-drop of a table - this seems like bad design to me unless it is very carefully controlled (which it sounds like it isn't). If you do have access to your source code (which it sounds like you do) I am thinking your time might be better spent just commenting out that deletion code so that your problem goes away.